# libGDX why does my fori loop not update Sprite position properly?

Tags: java, libgdx

So I created an "UpdateShopPosition" method, that should place Sprites in correct spots on the screen. However when I launch it in the render method, it seems that every Sprite shares the exact same position, not only that but the position keeps moving right and down.

I want MyX and MyY to have a different value for each shopList.get(i) . Is there a problem with the loop or is it because I placed this method in the render() section?

```
public class ObjectCreator {


public static int rowsX = 4;
public static int rowsY = 5;


    public static void UpdateShopPosition(List<Sprite> spriteList){
        for (int i = 0; i < spriteList.size(); i++) {



            float myX = playerSprite.getX() + ((i + 4) * 100);
            if (i > 0){
                myX+= i*3;
            }
            float myY = playerSprite.getY() + 410;
            if (i >= rowsX && i < rowsX*2 ) {
                myX = myX - 400;
                myY = myY - 101;
            }
            else if (i >= rowsX*2 && i < rowsX*3){
                myX = myX - 800;
                myY = myY - 202;
            }

            else if (i >= rowsX*3 && i < rowsX*4){
                myX = myX - 1200;
                myY = myY - 303;
            }
            else if (i >= rowsX*4 && i < rowsX*5){
                myX = myX - 1600;
                myY = myY - 404;
            }
            else if (i >= rowsX*5 && i < rowsX*6){
                myX = myX - 2000;
                myY = myY - 505;
            }

            spriteList.get(i).setPosition(myX, myY);
        }
    }

    public static void CreateUsable(Usables name, Sprite sprite){
        GameApp.shopList.add(sprite);


name.setImage(GameApp.shopList.get(0));



    }


}
```

```
 for (int i = 0; i < usableList.size(); i++) {
            usableList.get(i).draw(batch);
            usableList.get(i).setPosition(playerSprite.getX() - 1200, playerSprite.getY() + 300);
            usableList.get(i).setSize(60,60);
            // the next (i) should be placed on the next grid, so a little bit to the right
        }
```

I tried to create a method that keeps placing items sprites respectively to my player sprite, I want these sprites to have the same position no matter where I move on the map

Comment: You have a lot of "magic numbers" in that code. The whole chain of if/else-if/else could be eliminated by using a formula for calculating `myX` and for `myY`. It's hard to actually solve your issue since we don't know exactly what arrangement these sprites are *supposed* to have. Is it supposed to be a grid?

Comment: Yes, the inventory bag is made of grids, whenever I buy an item, a sprite is added to the Array list which stores sprites of items. Then, once an item is added to the Array, it should be positioned in the first empty grid there is. Whenever an item is added, and the grid is taken, the next item should be placed a bit to the right, if the whole row is taken, value Y -= ~100 and value X resets, I will update the code btw, since I posted a method which handles shop sprites instead.